# servicestack.redis does not save Dictionary Property

Tags: c#, .net, redis, servicestack

I have the following class:

```
public class UserSettings : IMongoEntity
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _id { get; private set; }

    [BsonElement("Uid")]
    public ObjectId UserId { get; set; }


    private Dictionary<string, StatusImportance> _imp;

    protected Dictionary<string, StatusImportance> ImportanceCollection
    {
        get {    
            if(_imp == null)
                _imp = new Dictionary<string, StatusImportance>();
        return _imp;
        }
        set { _imp = value; }
    }
 }
```

I save to Redis an object of this class with an ImportanceCollection with more than one object. Then when I get it again from the cache is null.

I'am using a RedisClient as a ICacheClient.

Any Ideas? Or RedisClient does not save dictionary properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ServiceStack's C# Redis Client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) uses [ServiceStack's JsonSerializer](http://www.servicestack.net/docs/text-serializers/json-serializer) which only serializes public members by default.

Comment: So what can i do if i want to store an object with private members and get it from cache later on?